# Java: Convert String containing days, hours, minutes to Date object

Tags: java, android, date

My application gives me a string like 1 day 15 min or 15 hours 10 min etc.
I would like to convert this string to Date object.
I was trying some thing like this

```
Date afterAddingTenMins = new Date(t + (Integer.valueOf(duration) * ONE_MINUTE_IN_MILLIS));
```

But this gives me invalid Integer exception because string contains words like hours and min.
What is the best way to do it.

Thank you.

Comment: depends on what the string format to parse.

Comment: Are you trying to take that string value and add it to the current time?

Comment: @JohnD. Yes I want to convert this string to date the nadd it to the current time and show an arrival date and time to the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ideal solution would be to change your data source to provide JSON or some other reliable format:

```
{
    days: 15,
    hours: 9,
    minutes: 30
}
```

Then you can use a JSON library to parse the data.

But if you're stuck dealing with that string, you can go the regex route like saka1029 mentioned, or even simpler, just manually parse the String:

```
String test = "15 hour 10 min";
    String[] testArray = test.split(" ");
    long additionalDuration = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < testArray.length; i+=2) {
        switch(testArray[i+1].toLowerCase()) {
            case "day":
            case "days":
                additionalDuration += Integer.parseInt(testArray[i]) * (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
                break;
            case "hour":
            case "hours":
                additionalDuration += Integer.parseInt(testArray[i]) * (1000 * 60 * 60);
                break;
            case "minute":
            case "minutes":
                additionalDuration += Integer.parseInt(testArray[i]) * (1000*60);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Could not parse unit: \""+testArray[i+1]+"\"");
        }
    }
    Date futureDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + additionalDuration);
```

Comment: I can not do that because my iOS application uses that format

Comment: Hence why I provided you with a string parsing method anyways.

Comment: Not relevant for the Question author, but FYI, there is a standard format of this type defined unambiguously by [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) called a Period or [Duration](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations): `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS` where `P` marks the beginning and `T` separates date and time-of-day portions. For example one day and 15 minutes is `P1DT15M`. The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library parses and generates such strings.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a scala version:

```
object PrettyTimeParser {
  private val YEAR_REGEX = """(?<YEAR>\d+)\s*years?""".r
  private val MONTH_REGEX = """(?<MONTH>\d+)\s*months?""".r
  private val WEEK_REGEX = """(?<WEEK>\d+)\s*weeks?""".r
  private val DAY_REGEX = """(?<DAY>\d+)\s*days?""".r
  private val HOUR_REGEX = """(?<HOUR>\d+)\s*hours?""".r
  private val MINUTE_REGEX = """(?<MINUTE>\d+)\s*minutes?""".r

  private def lookup(regex: scala.util.matching.Regex, s: String): Int = {
    Try(regex.findAllIn(s).toList.headOption.map(_.split(" ")).map(_(0).toInt)).getOrElse(None).getOrElse(0)
  }

  def parse(str: String): Option[DateTime] = {
    val year = lookup(YEAR_REGEX, str)
    val month = lookup(MONTH_REGEX, str)
    val week = lookup(WEEK_REGEX, str)
    val day = lookup(DAY_REGEX, str)
    val hour = lookup(HOUR_REGEX, str)
    val minute = lookup(MINUTE_REGEX, str)

    val now = DateTime.now()

    val dt = DateTime.now().plusYears(year)
      .plusMonths(month)
      .plusWeeks(week)
      .plusDays(day)
      .plusHours(hour)
      .plusMinutes(minute)

    if (dt.isAfter(now.getMillis)) Option(dt) else None
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract them by regex:

```
    String time = "1 day 15 min";
    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("(?<DAY>\\d+)\\s*days?|(?<HOUR>\\d+)\\s*hours?|(?<MIN>\\d+)\\s*min");
    Matcher m = pat.matcher(time);
    int day = 0, hour = 0, min = 0;
    while (m.find()) {
        if (m.group("DAY") != null) day = Integer.parseInt(m.group("DAY"));
        if (m.group("HOUR") != null) hour = Integer.parseInt(m.group("HOUR"));
        if (m.group("MIN") != null) min = Integer.parseInt(m.group("MIN"));
    }
    System.out.printf("%d day %d hour %d min%n", day, hour, min);
    // -> 1 day 0 hour 15 min
```

Comment: It is not working for me it gives error for strings "DAY", "HOUR" etc. I think group method requires it to be int